# Logfile full of '...mydomain.net/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat

Tags: logging

Whenever I check my logfile  most of it entries look like that with changing client ip

```
[Fri Nov 18 04:03:25 2016] [-:error] [pid 32060] [client 65.95.116.2XX] [host www.mydomain.net] script '/is/htdocs/www/mydomain.net/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
```

I do not understand this, because `wp-login.php` is a Wordpress File and my website is not build on wordpress. Are customers constantly checking if my website is build on WP, or is there an army of bots trying to find that out? Or is there another reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are - usually - bots (or scripts, or whatever you can think of) trying to find vulnerabilities on your webserver. If you look further, you can probably find many other entries like that, e.g. `"GET /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.0"`, even if you don't run PHPMyAdmin.